# Refreshed information upon click

Tags: javascript

I'm using D3.JS's Collapsing Tree Diagram (https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460) to model information.

I've created a search form so that when a keyword is typed, a specific node and its children appear, alongside additional information that is matched with the keyword (the specific parent node).  For instance, if I type "Burger" into the search form, "Burger" and its children nodes will appear but only information about "Burger" will appear on the side.  I want to make it so that when I click a child node of "Burger", such as "French Fry", the information for "French Fry" will refresh and appear in place of the information for "Burger."

I've turned off the collapse function of the diagram because I want to be able to click the children nodes of the parent node and have the additional information to be updated based on that child node, instead of the parent node.

How would I approach this using Javascript or JQuery?  I'm still new to coding so any help would be wonderful.  Thank you and please let me know if further clarification is necessary.

Comment: If your code is very similar to the example take a very close look at the click function.  `function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
  } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
 }` Think along the lines of how this function affects your app.

Comment: @Callat I'm using all my brain power and I still cannot figure it out.